# Sci-fi children's book with an alien football mascot named Mookiee?

Tags: story-identification, aliens, childrens-novel, powers

I remember when I was EXTREMELY young, I read a very non-descript children's book with an alien character named Mookiee who served as the mascot of a middle-school football team on Earth. I can't really remember the plot but I do remember that Mookiee's eyes had rotating colors in them that were (possibly) having something to do with his powers. Does anybody know what I'm talking about?

Comment: Is it _about_ Mookie, or is Mookie just one of the characters?

Comment: He’s just one of the characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds very much like *[Aliens in the Endzone](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/363249)*, the second book in the *[Screammates](https://www.goodreads.com/series/269228-screammates)* series, published in 1998.

The plot concerns a middle-school American football team called "The Rockets". From a Goodreads review:

> Johnny Nielson is the star running back on his youth football team,
> the Rockville Rockets. They reeled off seven wins to start the season,
> but are currently in a slump that could cost them a shot at the state
> championship. Their school principal has a solution: the introduction
> of a team mascot, a strange-looking green man named **"Mookie the
> Martian**."

It turns out that Mookie is a real alien, who escaped to Earth to get away from a bully. Unfortunately it turns out that a rival team also has a new mascot - who turns out to be Mookie's old bully, Vandor.

> Vandor has a deal for Mookie: if Rockville wins the championship,
> Vandor will leave him alone permanently. But if Westport wins...Vandor
> will destroy the planet. The two aliens take turns meddling in the
> game action, the score staying close as the clock ticks toward the
> end. Johnny and Kristen are the only players who know what's at stake,
> but can they deliver the winning play under pressure, saving both
> Mookie and Earth from Vandor? It all comes down to a final field goal
> attempt...